# You must define CA file (OpenVPN)

Tags: openvpn

Monday morning all clients, who connected to my OpenVPN server, don't have an internet, but connection is successfully.

In the log file I see:

```
systemd[1]: openvpn@base.service: Service RestartSec=5s expired, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: openvpn@base.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 63235.
ovpn-base[32719]: Options error: You must define CA file (--ca) or CA path (--capath)
ovpn-base[32719]: Use --help for more information.
systemd[1]: openvpn@base.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: openvpn@base.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

These rows repeat every 5 seconds.
How to fix it?
How to define CA file or check it?

Comment: Looks like something went off with your encryption certificate. Did you use a self-signed certificate? Even that will have an expiration date built-in, which may have expired.

Comment: I usually generate certificates using easy-rsa `./build-key username`. In the `index.txt` I see that expiration date is 2026 year and time on the server settuped correctly.